# How Upgrade SQLite Data without losing old version data in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have one app which I already published V1 which have an SQLite Database but in V2 I updated Database Schema, My question is this how do I migrate database without losing data which already exists.

Comment: please check the onUpgrade method in SQLite

Comment: https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is this how do I migrate database without losing data
>   which already exists.

It's possible. You should read [**`onUpgrade`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int)) at first.

> public abstract void onUpgrade (SQLiteDatabase db, 
>                       int oldVersion, 
>                       int newVersion)

Called when the database needs to be upgraded. The implementation should use this method to drop tables, add tables, or do anything else it needs to upgrade to the new schema version.

**EXAMPLE**

If you add new column then,

```
@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {      
          Log.e("VERSION", "Updating table from " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion);
           if (oldVersion < Your_New_version){
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_NAME  + " ADD COLUMN new_column_name TEXT;");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, man this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1; //<<**Increase the database 
version** here 
//when you make any database schema changes
....

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Note.TABLE_NAME); // take the respective action

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

}
```

................
the above changes will work fine but if you have already lauched your app then you have following options:
1) **go for force update**
2) If you have maintain the session token in header (while API hit) then discuss with your backend team to give 404 error code(any) on invalid token and you make logout handling on that error code, so when user login then all data will be fresh to store. (If you don't have any logout handling then this way is not recommended).

Comment: but what about user data it will secure when I upgrade database schema?

Comment: go for force update

Comment: Thanks, man for answer

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to override [onUpgrade](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int)) method of [SQLiteOpenHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper)

Refer this gist for a sample - https://gist.github.com/mlnkrish/eeed1cfa9c11f6d37841

Comment: Okay, I will check out thank you your time